# How to specify a bottom_margin for ScrollView in java class

Tags: java, android, scrollview, margin

How to specify a bottom_margin for ScrollView in java class
specify when the user approaches the end of the page, define a bottom_margin of 20dp.
I've already defined bottom_margin in XML but at the end it'll be like this when it is in the middle of the activity :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L69cX.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```xml
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    your content ..

</ScrollView>
```

You don't set the bottom margin (on the outside), you add padding (on the inside) and set `clipToPadding` to false.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work when I did that. you know what, I want a little space at the end of the page but I don't want that space to be appeared when it is in the middle of the page and when I tried your code there was no space at the and of the page and even no padding.

Comment: If that doesn't work, it would help if you edited your question and added your layout file.